Windows Terminal: repeated key-mappings do not work properly
I'm using Windows 10. In Windows Terminal, I want to map the Ctrl-_ (control-underscore) to null in order for it to have no function.
In the "actions" section of my Windows Terminal settings.json file, I have this:
{
    "command":
    {
        "action": "sendInput",
        "input": "\u0000"
    },
    "keys": "ctrl+_"
}

This works properly for the first time I type Ctrl-_, but if I type this repeatedly (for example, Ctrl-_Ctrl-_Ctrl-_Ctrl-_), only the first instance does nothing, and the following three instances each insert a newline.
This same thing occurs no matter what I set the "input" value to. For example, if for testing purposes I set "input" to "A" in the config file, and if I then type the same four-time repeated Ctrl-_ character, I see an "A" followed by three newlines on the screen.
How can I configure Windows Terminal to always echo the specified "input" character however many times I might decide to repeat the Ctrl-_?
And this seems to work the same way no matter which key sequence I decide to map via the "keys" attribute. In other words, this behavior is not specific only to Ctrl-_ remapping.
Thank you very much in advance.
UPDATE: I just realized something about this. If I hold down the Ctrl and Shift keys and repeatedly click the "-" key (whose upper case output is underscore), it works as I describe above. However, if I remove my fingers from Ctrl and Shift after hitting the "-" key and then replace my fingers again on Ctrl and Shift in before I retype each following Ctrl-_ instance, then this works fine.
So ... apparently Windows Terminal does not remember the Ctrl and Shift state that is still in effect when repeated instances of the remapped key are entered. Is there any way to get Windows Terminal to remember these Ctrl and Shift states between consecutive key presses of other keys that are affected by the current Ctrl and Shift state?
FURTHER CLARIFICATION: I now realize that I can use "unbound" instead of "command" in the config file to disable a key, and this would alleviate the specific problem that I describe above. However, I also want to remap some other keys to actual character values, and these keys can be repeatedly entered in the same way that I describe above ... i.e., just like the "A" case that I mentioned. So, this forgetting of the Ctrl and Shift state between repeated presses of the same key is still a problem within Windows Terminal that I'd like to solve.

Perhaps a third-party tool, such as AutoHotkey, can "eat" that keypress... or not.

Only Microsoft can solve the problem in Terminal. As said, a third-party tool can solve it from outside of Terminal, if you're interested.

Thanks to both of you. I guess I'm out of luck, because I'm running this at work in a highly locked-down environment, and we users are not allowed to install any third-party software. I'll request that the powers that be install something like AutoHotkey, but until they do that (assuming they actually agree to do it), I'll just work around this problem somehow.

I'm guessing this is something specific to "ctrl+_". Probably because, as you observed, _ is technically shift+minus.
If I do instead:
        {
            "command": 
            {
                "action": "sendInput",
                "input": "a"
            },
            "keys": "ctrl+shift+minus"
        },

it seems to work as expected?

Thank you very much. However, when I do this, it behaves the same as I reported above: if I hold down Ctrl and Shift and repeat "-" four times, I get the letter "a" followed by three newlines. I have to let go of Ctrl and Shift and re-press both of those keys before each repeated "-" in order for "a" to be output each time. In other words, the Ctrl/Shift state doesn't get remembered between consecutive "-" keypresses, as I reported above.
